# How to highlight code samples through AngularJS using Prismjs and TinyMCE

Tags: angularjs, tinymce, highlight, tinymce-4, prism.js

I have a tinyMCE plugin in my angular app where the user can insert code into a mysql database.

I want to highlight those inserted codes retrieved from my database.

For that reason,  I used prismjs as TinyMCE uses it by [default](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/codesample/).
I'm able to customize and highlight a code sample directly with TinyMCE. But once inserted in the database and retrieve it for displaying, the code sample could't be highlighted although I imported prism.css and prism.js as well in my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="prism.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        //...
    </head>
    //...
    <body>
         //...
        <script src="angular_1_6.min.js"></script>
        <script src="MyCtrl.js"></script>
        <script src="prism.js"></script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Here is an example of a result string from my database:

```
<pre class="language-markup"><code>&lt;div class="alert alert-danger" id="question-error" role="alert" ng-if="showQuestionError"&gt;
        &lt;button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" ng-click="showQuestionError=false"&gt;
            &lt;span aria-hidden="true"&gt;&amp;times;&lt;/span&gt;
        &lt;/button&gt;
        &lt;strong&gt;Erreur ! Merci de v&eacute;rifier que le titre de la question : &lt;/strong&gt;
        &lt;ul &gt;
            &lt;li&gt;Se termnine par un point d'interrogation (?).&lt;/li&gt;
            &lt;li&gt;Ne d&eacute;passe pas 150 caract&egrave;res.&lt;/li&gt;
            &lt;li&gt;Et n'est pas vide.&lt;/li&gt;
        &lt;/ul&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;</code></pre>
```

PS: SO parses it, normally the tag div tag just above is wrapped by :

```
<pre class="language-markup"></pre>
```

Please what can I do ?

Comment: Please add the result string you recive from the DB.

Comment: Done, see the édit please 

Comment: I belive you need to insert the data as non escaped string into TinyMCE. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes I think. In fact, there is a button in the TinyMCE toolbar that allow us to add code, (codesample) and it highlights it afterward .

Comment: I'm talking about the data you retrieve from the DB where your error is comming from. Add  it as non escaped string into TinyMCE.

Comment: I did, but nothing change

Comment: Please create a plunker to reproduce your error.

Comment: Here is the plunker link https://plnkr.co/edit/GmCZeXY0WNu5WLYduAwt?p=preview. I can not figure out how to use the latest version of tinyMCE (v4.5). But my code looks like this

Comment: So is your issue reloading the code into TinyMCE itself or are you wanting the code highlighting outside of TinyMCE when the content is later rendered on the finished web page?

Comment: highlighting outside of TinyMCE when the content is later rendered on the finished web page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the content is loaded on a "regular" web page you need to make sure of two things:

1. Prism's files are loaded on the page
2. You tell Prism to search the page and markup content that is a code sample.

The first part is discussed here:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/codesample/#usingprismjsonyourwebpage

In specific you need to have a CSS and JS file on the page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="prism.css">
<script src="prism.js"></script>
```

If you have this on the page before the HTML to be highlighted is loaded that should be all you need to do.  If you are loading the code dynamically you can manually tell Prism to search the page for code to markup:

http://prismjs.com/extending.html#api

The `Prism.highlightAll()` command will tell Prism to search the entire page and do its magic on any code samples.

Comment: Amazing ! It works super really great           Thx